# Bootstrap tooltip stops working after any other event runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I'm using tooltips in Bootstrap v3.2.0. They all work as they should when the page first loads, but if I do anything on the page that involves running som js code, they stop working. At least that's my first impression of the problem.

I initiate my tooltips like so:

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
```

And this is the code I use for a tooltip:

```
<span class='my-tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'><i class='fa fa-info'></i></span>
```

As I said, the tooltip initially works, but when I do anything on the page that involves running some js, the tooltip stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after posting this question, i realised the problem. My tooltip exists inside a cart, that is rebuilt each time I add a product to it. I needed to re initiate my tooltip each time I rebuild my cart.